# How can I search in a richTextBox text for a text not a single word/string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If in textBox1 I type for example: Form1
Then I will get many results and it will highlight this results in yellow.

But when I copy paste to the textBox1 some text not only Form1 for example:

```
if ((null != _FileProcessingWorker) && (_FileProcessingWorker.IsBusy))
{
    _FileProcessingWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```

Then it will not color it in yellow. For some reason it's working only for single words/strings but it's not working for a block of text.

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(
            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndices[0]
            ].Text);

        int start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int index = 0;
        string word = textBox1.Text;
        Color selectionColor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;

        while ((index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(index, word.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
            startIndex = index + word.Length;
        }

        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = selectionColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is caused by a feature of your RichTextBox. When a text is loaded in the control it converts the carriage return line feed ("\r\n") combinations into a line feed. The Textbox however leaves line-endings untouched.

You can easily verify that by copying

> line one
>   line two

in both the TextBox and RichtTextBox and then inspect their Text properties:

[image: text inspection]

The simplest solution is to replace the "\r\n"  characters in textBox1 with "\n" so they match the line-endings used in the RichTextBox:

```
string word = textBox1.Text;
Color selectionColor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;

// match line-endings
word = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

while ((index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
{
// your other code
}
```

|